# Convert Gloss JSON to Data in swift 3.0

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am struggling to convert Gloss JSON object into Data in swift 3.0. I want to send multipart request to API with image and some json payload. I'm new to swift and IOS in general, so answer to this question might be obvious.

I have a class like this:

```
import Gloss

struct RepoOwner: Decodable {

    let ownerId: Int?
    let username: String?

    // MARK: - Deserialization

    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.ownerId = "id" <~~ json
        self.username = "login" <~~ json
    }

    func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
            "id" ~~> self.ownerId,
            "login" ~~> self.username
        ])
    }

}
```

And then I want to send a multipart request like this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    if let repoOwner = self.repoOwner, let json = repoOwner.toJSON() {

                        data = // TODO: Help me!
                        multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "payload")
                        multipartFormData.append(self.imageData, withName: "image")
                    }
                },
                to: "https://myapi.com/endpoint",
                encodingCompletion: { ... }
                }
        )
```

Can anybody help me?